# Find all fields of a document in pyMongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to find all the fields of a document using `pymongo` for performing retrieving data from them. The code below is giving all the documents with its all fields. But can we find all fields or keys of a document?

```
f = db['Collection'].find()
for i in f:
    print(i['Date'])
```

I can get all the documents `ObjectId` from

```
print(db['Collection'].distinct("_id"))
```

Now we have `ids` of all documents. Can we find fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PyMongo `find()` method returns a [Cursor](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) instance, which allows you to iterate over all matching documents. The documents in your iteration is a [Python Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), so you can list all of its keys using `keys()` method, for example:

```
cursor = db['collection'].find({})
for document in cursor: 
    print(document.keys())  # print all fields of this document.
```

Having said the above, generally you should know the fields in your collection. 
If you want to query documents that contain certain fields see operator [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/).

Comment: Can also works as `cursor = db['collection'].find()` . Can we find fields by giving `_id` of a document? Not giving collection name.

Comment: A database can contain many collections, a collection can contain many documents. Specifying only `_id` without collection name, does not quite make sense.

Comment: Okay. By giving collection name and then `_id` of a specific document? For example as `db['collection']['_id']`? or like as `document[ObjectId('57e35fca05cbcd1c385081a0')]`?

Comment: You could try: `db['collection'].find_one({'_id':ObjectId('57e35fca05cbcd1c385081a0')}).keys()`. What is your goal ? Querying all documents in a collection one by one could be an expensive operation depending on the size of the collection.

Comment: Thanks it is working perfect. I will keep in mind the expensive operation.